# XAMPP - allow access over network?

Tags: windows, networking, xampp, shared-folders

I have XAMPP installed, as usual, on my C drive.

I'd like another computer on the network to have write access to it.

Must I move (i.e. reinstall) XAMPP to a shared folder, or is there anyway I can set up a sort of bridge to where it is currently? (I'm assuming not, since write access to the C drive is obviously risky as a concept. Here, though, it's just my other machine in another room of the house.)

My other machine can access my main machine via Samba (\x.x.x.x) but that, of course, just brings up the shared folders, not C.

Comment: Can't you share XAMPP's folder too just like you did with the others?

Comment: I didn't explicitly share those other folders; they just appear anyway, so I guess they're shared by default. Good call, though, I'll see if I can share the XAMPP folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can just share your `c:\xampp\htdocs` folder and it'll appear in the shared folders on your network when users go to the UNC of the machine.

No need to move it.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be about how to get other PCs on the network viewing the served output. I'm talking about them being able to edit the files, via Samba.